# What parts of the Code of Criminal Procedure deal with appeal from a sentence?

Tags: criminal-law, india, appeal, indian-penal-code, sentencing

I've been browsing through the Indian Penal Code (IPC) and the Code of Criminal Procedure (CrPc) and there doesn't seem to be any provision for appeals from sentencing (reduction) there seems to be sections for enhancing it (section 377 and section 378) are there any provisions I'm missing or not reading properly?

Answer (score 1):

[Section 374](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_000010_197402_1517807320555&orderno=420) CrPc gives the general right of appeal, but there are exclusions, such as those found within [section 375](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_000010_197402_1517807320555&orderno=421) and [section 376](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_000010_197402_1517807320555&orderno=422).

Although s.374 does not mention on what grounds an appeal may be laid, an alleged unduly harsh sentence is permitted (as long as the correct procedural processes are followed) as it is not expressly excluded anywhere within the CrPc.

In fact, it is specifically referenced within [section 385](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_000010_197402_1517807320555&orderno=431):

> (3) Where the only ground for **appeal from a conviction is the alleged severity of the sentence**, the appellant shall not, except with the leave of the Court, urge or be heard in support of any other ground.